# how can i order by relevance in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

i have a query happening

```
contractors = User.all

@tools = Tool.all

tools_list = []

    @tools.each do |t|
        if params[t.name]
            tools_list.push("#{t.name}")
        end
    end

contractors = contractors.joins(:tools).where('tools.name IN (?) ', tools_list).uniq
```

so this looks through my params and then if a tool in the list is found  it adds it to an array and then searches for all people that have at least one of these tools in there tools set.

my question is how do i then order my results so that the people with all of the tools specified come out at the top of the list and then people with less come below?

so to clarify at the moment i get a list in no particular order of all of my contractors that have at least one of the tools specified. how do i order that list so that people with more of the tools appear on the top of the list and people with less appear on the bottom?

Thank you in advance with any help :)

Comment: _Sidenote_: `tools_list = @tools.map { |t| t.name if params[t.name] }.compact` is your 6 lines for setting `tools_list` written in ruby.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try this, most of SQL clauses (if not all of them) are defined in ActiveRecord:

```
User
  .joins(:tools)
  .select('users.*, count(tools.id) "counting"')
  .where(tools: { name: tools_list })
  .having('counting > 0')
  .group('users.id')
  .order('counting DESC')
```

Comment: Order should be `DESC`.

Comment: Also, please make the code smartphone screen friendly (put chained methods on their own lines.)

Comment: I never thought about it (I use to browse SO on my laptop). Fixed as well

Comment: i think its on the right track but this feeds to a visual list of contractors that have names , pictures , locations and so on. really i just need to list the returned contractors but relevance to the search params.

Comment: Ok, I just added `where` clause to it, also, you can change params you want to retrieve from the query, i've changed it to `select('users.*...`, so you'll have all user fields

Comment: You sir are a very handsom man! that is near enough exactly what i need! im sure i can adapt it from here! Thank you very much for all your help!